# Operators for Node.getAttribute evaluated inconsistently

Tags: javascript, operators

I seem to have stumbled upon what seems like a false equivalency, 
generating a list of all inputs for the wikipedia homepage (wikipedia.org) with:

`var inputs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("input"));`

gets me a list of all inputs, however, the `<input#searchInput>` node with a `type=search` attribute seems to be evaluating very strangely.

`inputs[2].getAttribute('type') === ("text" || "search")` evaluates to `false` whereas

`inputs[2].getAttribute('type') === ("search" || "text")` evaluates to `true`.

Can anyone explain the logic in this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `getAttribute`, but that you have to do `value === "text" || value === "search"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term (string || string) seems to evaluate to whatever is the first non null value, or null if both are null, which makes sense.

So `("text" || "search")` results to `"text"`. In that logic, it evaluates the comparison in the parentheses and then does: `inputs[2].getAttribute('type') === "text"`, which is `false`

To prove this, try out the following code which should return true:

`inputs[2].getAttribute('type') === (null || "search")`